# Parsing a string representation of a uint64 to a haxe.Int64

Tags: haxe

I have a a string representation of a big integer, in this case "1083715881696", which I would like to place in a numeric variable.

If I do:

```
var int:Int = Std.parseInt("1083715881696");
```

It fails, and I get the result `2147483647` which is 0x7FFFFFFF in hex.

I'd like something like a Std.parseInt64 function, basically -- what's the logical equivalent? I assume the type I'm going to want to store it in here is [haxe.Int64](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/Int64.html), as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Next version of Haxe will have such helper: https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/development/std/haxe/Int64Helper.hx#L30

If you want to use it today you can use thx.core: http://thx-lib.org/api/thx/Int64s.html

If your big-integers are really big you can also use: http://thx-lib.org/api/thx/BigInt.html